# Наличие каких сертификатов по языку R считается престижным для новичка?

Tags: r

Наличие каких сертификатов по языку R считается престижным для новичка?
Да и вообще порекомендуйте как получить первую работу в качестве программиста на языке R?

Answer (score 1):

При работе с R престижным считается публикация своих пакетов в https://cran.r-project.org/
А первую работу получить элементарно -  твердо учите язык, твердо учите соответствующую прикладную область, скорее всего связанную с со статистикой, анализом данных и пр.,  - и первая работа у вас в кармане. Хотя есть еще вариант - во время получения соответствующего   магистерского (а лучше - phD) уровня устраиваетесь на работу по специальности - часто даже не за деньги, а за "науку", а после окончания учебы - если зарекомендуете себя должным образом - переходите в штат.

Comment: Плюсом к CRAN будет публикация в Journal of Statistical Software.